# How to get connection origin in SignalR 2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, cors, signalr

I'm creating SignalR server that will be hosting JavaScript and .net clients and I need to limit JavaScript calls only from one domain (mydomain.com).
Currently I'm using **CorsOptions.AllowAll** option and I know I can set my custom Cors Policy like **.Origins.Add("mydomain.com");**.

My question is : If I set custom policy like .Origin.Add("mydomain.com") will .net client be able to connect?

If you have any other idea how to limit JavaScript (web) calls to one domain, and allow all .net clients I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is : If I set custom policy like .Origin.Add("mydomain.com") will .net client be able to connect?

Yes. .net clients are completely unaffected by any CORS headers/config you set on the server.

Browsers are the only clients that [use those server response headers to enforce CORS restrictions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)